# VAR, Algebra and local presentability

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra, limits-colimits, higher-category-theory

[Here](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/tmj.2017.10.issue-3/tmj-2017-0113/tmj-2017-0113.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, on the page 282, I would like to understand why precisely Examples of $k$-ary operations are all $k-\mathrm{lim}$, BUT $k-\textrm{colim}$ must be filtered. Where have we used that $k$ is filtered and **how** taking $k$-colim becomes an operation? And yet, on that page  282 above those examples, what is the difference between $\ast$ and $\cdot$ in the equation
$$\omega_{G\cdot F}=(G\ast\omega_F)\cdot (\omega_G\ast F)?$$ What squares these $\ast$ and $\cdot$ amounts to commute?
I more or less understand what comes next in the paper, but for this page.

<sup>1</sup> Jiří Adámek and Jiří Rosický: Algebra and local presentability: how algebraic are they? (A survey); Tbilisi Mathematical Journal 10(3) (2017), pp. 279–295; DOI: [10.1515/tmj-2017-0113](https://doi.org/10.1515/tmj-2017-0113)

Comment: There seems to be no reason to create the tag "var." It seems to be much too specific. It doesn't even have a wikipedia page. See here for guidelines on tag creation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug

Answer (score 0):

Morphisms of varieties preserve limits and filtered colimits, but not general colimits. This is essentially the definition of an operation on VAR. The $*$ denotes whiskering a functor with a natural transformation, while $\cdot$ denotes (vertical) composition of natural transformations. All the authors are doing here is spelling out the meaning of pseudonatural transformation, which you can find in more verbose form in many places.

Comment: Yes, but could you please possibly draw the few commuting squares with labels so that I would easily understand which compositions are meant here? For whiskering as well as for vertical composition?

Comment: @user122424 I would prefer you just look up the definition of pseudonatural transformation. It's a bit annoying to type diagrams on here.

Comment: OK, and can you please help by giving me a reference at least?

Comment: Just try Googling the phrase. It's a very standard concept.